# CSS Reset table to default equivalent

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am working with a pre-made bought template, where the author of said template wired things together in such a way where its next to impossible sometimes to get something the way you want, in this case I have a table I am trying to put in to a section of the template, that I don't need or want styled the way they have the template do it. However because of how they did it I can't just go altering the CSS to do something else. I have tried classing the table as something else and styling it the way I want, but there's something that always manages to get snagged somewhere and the author's style persists on one piece or another of the table. So with that I came up with the idea, why not make a reset like class specific to tables that I can call this class in first on the element, then the class I want it to be styled under e.g.:

`class="reset_table mynew_style"`

So I am trying to come up with a means of doing it, but am getting stuck.

```
.reset_table, 
.reset_table table tr,
.reset_table tr td,
.reset_table table tbody,
.reset_table table thead,
.reset_table table tfoot,
.reset_table table tr th,
.reset_table table tfoot tr tf
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:none;
    border:none;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    background-image:none;
}
```

Now this seems to work almost completely, there's still some things persisting. So I'm hoping someone here can help me come up with a better variation of this. So all bases are covered in the sense of trying to reset a table back to normal default style.

Comment: Try using an id instead of a class.  ids are more specific.

Comment: That would be ideal, if there was only a single instance of a table I wish to reset the style on, but on a couple pages, theres multiples where I need to apply some outside the initial authors spec custom styling to make elements fit in. But as I said the author wired it together in such away that its close to impossible to do anything with tables. Unless they are intended to conform to the templates design

Comment: You could use `!important` as a last resort.  Can you give some examples of what is persisting?  Another alternative would be add an id/class to the html tag if possible and then style your tables from there with a class.

Comment: currently it appear for the moment, the `table > thead > tr` or that plus `> th` is stuck with its padding/margin and background. Just about everything else has for the most part reset using the above

Comment: The > selector may be more specific, try altering your styles to be `.reset_table table > table > thead > tr` and see if that works.

Comment: What properties are still persisting? With an element inspector like Chrome's or Firebug you can see exactly which properties are still showing through, and the selectors that are causing them. Also, if you want to save a bit of headache, you could use .reset_table * as a selector

Comment: seeing as I wrote this a year ago.. I don't remember.. the problem is no longer my concern. I think I had finally fixed it though, but I have since finished that project and handed it over to the owner. Though its still something nice to know.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's an old thread, but in case this is helps someone else:

```
.clear-user-agent-styles table,
.clear-user-agent-styles thead,
.clear-user-agent-styles tbody,
.clear-user-agent-styles tfoot,
.clear-user-agent-styles tr,
.clear-user-agent-styles th,
.clear-user-agent-styles td {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-collapse: inherit;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-color: inherit;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: inherit;
    -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0;
    -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0;
}
.clear-user-agent-styles th,
.clear-user-agent-styles td {
    display: inline;
}
```

If it's still not overriding other dev styles, make sure you have this code after theirs, or be more specific by including the parent class, or even ID if you need to. Try, to avoid appending *!important* to the end of each property's value, but that would mostly likely trump what was coded previously.

Comment: @PaulBrunache - No problem! I wish being semantic didn't have to be such a styling battle with tables, but this freed it up for me to do responsive stuff more easily.

Comment: `display:block` is not right for `table`, `tr`, or `td`. Nor is `inline`.

Comment: Note that `vertical-align` is ignored when `display: block` is set.